# Marking an e-mail as unread pops a "new email" notification

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications, gmail

My wife and I both have Samsung Galaxy S2 phones, and use the GMail app for reading and writing emails.

In that app, when I mark a read mail as "unread", it throws me back into the previous screen and correctly marks the mail as unread.

When my wife marks a mail as unread, however, it does the same, but also adds a "new email" notification which then appears in the top bar - which really annoys her.

What is the cause of this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you compared your Gmail app settings to see what the difference is?

Comment: You could try re-installing the app on her phone.

Comment: Or purge the app's cache.